# Getting td by index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing, html-table

I know how to get a cell's row and column index with jQuery, but I can't figure out the reverse. Given a row and column index, how would I access the td at this location?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

With plain JavaScript:

```
// table is a reference to your table
table.rows[rowIndex].cells[columnIndex]
```

**Reference:** [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableElement), [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement)

---

With jQuery, you could use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('#table tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(columnIndex)
// or
$('#table tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ') td:eq(' + columnIndex + ')')
```

Comment: How about that - plain property access, not a single function call in sight. :-)

Comment: What's this? A JavaScript answer without a `$` in sight? +1!

Answer (score 12):

How about using the `nth-child` selector?

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
var row = 4;
var col = 2

var cell = $('table#tableId tr:nth-child(' + row + ') td:nth-child(' + col + ')');
```

Note that the child index is 1-based, rather than the more usual 0-based.

Comment: This is the perfect, perfectly cryptic jQuery answer. It's the one I used. One line and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:eq` selector:

```
var row = 1;
var col = 2;
var cell = $('table tr:eq(' + row + ') td:eq(' + col + ')');
```

Here's an [example of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/feXUP/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another PURE JavaScript example. See the bottom of the HTML for the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- [Getting td by index with jQuery (N.B. also tagged javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139407/getting-td-by-index-with-jquery) 
  used table from [javascript: getting td index [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470877/javascript-getting-td-index)
  -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>1</th> <th>2</th> <th>3</th></tr>
    </thead>
  
    <tbody>
      <tr><td onclick="showIx(this)">data</td> <td onclick="showIx(this)">checkbox</td> <td onclick="showIx(this)">data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
<script>
  function showIx(myTDobj){
    /** 
     * see [cellIndex >> HTMLTableCellElement - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement)
     */
    alert(myTDobj.cellIndex);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Love and peace,

Joe