# jquery Datatables get clicked column index trought row id

Tags: datatables

i have a datable ( #mydatatable ) where i "delegate" an onclick event for each row in it. I can access to the row index like so in following code:

```
$('#mydatatable').delegate('tr', 'click', function(event) {
    var oSettings = oTable.dataTable().fnSettings();
    var iTotalRecords = oSettings.fnRecordsTotal();
    if(iTotalRecords > 0){      
        var gIDNumber = $(this).attr('id'); // Table ROW index here
            getCellFromTr($(this)); 
    }           
});
```

But i can´t figure it out, how to get the column index where i cliked:

```
function getCellFromTr(t){  
  var row = t.parent().children().index(); // This also give's me the row index
  alert('row: ' + row);     
}
```

Can someone help me out with this please...

Thank you

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470877/javascript-getting-td-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470877/javascript-getting-td-index)

Comment: thx i already found a workaround...