# Finding td element position in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about finding a td element's position in a table row? I have seen this code suggested, but is there a way to do this with having each td tag contain an onclick event?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">Click to show cellIndex</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">Click to show cellIndex</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">Click to show cellIndex</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">Click to show cellIndex</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script>
 function myFunction(x) {
   alert("Cell index is: " + x.cellIndex);
}
</script>
```

I have a grid of images and I am trying to see which images in the grid have been clicked. I tried this:

```
$('td img').on('click', function(x){
   console.log("Cell index is: " + x.cellIndex); 
});
```

But it just logs `undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: getting td index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470877/javascript-getting-td-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('td img').on('click', function(e) {
  var td = $(this).parent();
  var tr = td.parent();
  
  var children = tr.children().length;
  
  var tdIndex = td.index() + 1;
  var trIndex = tr.index();
  
  console.log((trIndex * children) + tdIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="1.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="2.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="1.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="2.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I had a large grid, say, 8 x 8, would the index start over again at zero once I clicked the first image in the second row?

Comment: Yes, but I just edited my snippet to accomplish with your request.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('table tr td').click(function() {

  console.log($(this).index()) //use index() to get the index of clicked td

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Click to show cellIndex|</td>
    <td>Click to show cellIndex|</td>
    <td>Click to show cellIndex|</td>
    <td>Click to show cellIndex|</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

attach a click to td and use `.index()` to get the index of click td

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JavaScript, you could handle it like so:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
for(var i = 0, len = tds.length; i < len; i++) {
    tds[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var td = this || (e || event).target;
        alert(td.cellIndex)
  });
}
```

Attaching the `onclick` event to each `TD` element on the page. Here's a [Fiddle of it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/ocu7rzns/), and with jQuery you just need to specify what the `x` is referencing.

```
$('td').on('click', function(e){
    alert('this.cellIndex: ' + this.cellIndex + '\n$(this),index(): ' + $(this).index());
});
```

[Documentation on event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Answer (score 2):

You can use $.index() function in jquery to get the object's index

https://api.jquery.com/index/

```
 function myFunction(x) {
   alert($(x).index());
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `.index()` on the element that you are trying to get the index of.

```
$('td img').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/407u4Lp2/1/