# Jquery to get particular text area under a selected td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am required to select a particular Textarea with id= abc inside the 3rd td of a collection of tr's in "coll" variable. By below code I am able to get the collection of . Now I need to get the 3rd td and the textarea inside it.

```
var coll = $('iframe[id=iframeID]').contents().find('.trClass');
```

HTML is something like this

```
<tr>
 <td>
 <td>
   <textarea>
 <td>
   <textarea>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <textarea>
 <td>
   <textarea>
 <td>
</tr>
```

Updating my question a bit. I am able to get value of text area by using the below code. But that gives me the value of textarea of 2nd td of first tr. there are collection of 's. how to get the value of textarea of 2nd td of each tr.

```
var coll = $('iframe[id=iframeID]').contents().find('.Rowclass').find('‌​td:eq(2)').find('tex‌​tarea').val();
```

Comment: Please add html

Comment: Why not targetting it by id, it should be unique, right?

Comment: thats not the point, id aur class thats is not issue, i need to get 2nd td inside each tr

Comment: Second td, ok... Use tr td:eq(1)...

Comment: You say "select a particual text area with id"... then what is the issue? select it by id or explain your question better

Comment: because it is not just one text area it can be multiple with in different td i need to check if the text area will be empty or not and then apply my css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with `eq` element if you use jquery already. Try that:

```
var coll = $('iframe[id=iframeID]').contents().find('.trClass').find('td:eq(2)');
```

Comment: ok now I have to change the textarea color inside that td if its empty

Comment: I tried below code and I got the value in textarea of 2nd td of first tr. I need the value of text areas of 2nd td in other tr as well


var coll = $('iframe[id=iframeID]').contents().find('.Rowclass').find('td:eq(2)').find('textarea').val();

Comment: ok finally was able to figure out.. guess was lacking in calling the array of rows. for anyone who is looking for here is my code: 

var TRCount= $('iframe[id*="DlgFrame"]').contents().find('.rgEditRow').length;
for (var i = 0; i < TRCount; i++) {
if($($('iframe[id*="DlgFrame"]').contents().find('.rgEditRow')[i]).find('td:eq(2)').find('textarea').val()== ""){
    
            $($('iframe[id*="DlgFrame"]').contents().find('.rgEditRow')[i]).find('td:eq(2)').find('textarea').css("background-color","red");
           
       } }

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var coll =$('iframe[id=iframeID]').contents().find('.trClass').find('td').eq(2);
```

From Following Suggested StackOverFlow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139407/getting-td-by-index-with-jquery)