# change table data to corresponding one in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html-table

I have a web app, backend using Django, frontend using HTML5.

In the HTML5 page, there's a table, the data are from restful API.
I want to change the table data in JavaScript, that is, I want a different table data in different JavaScript if conditions.

```
<table id = "thisTable"
contenteditable = 'true'
class = "table table-bordered table-sm"
width = "100%"
cellspacing = "0"
style = "font-size: 1.0rem;"
id = "bk-table"
data - toggle = "table"
data - toolbar = "#toolbar"
data - cookie = "true"
data - cookie - id - table = "materialId"
data - show - columns = "true"
data - show - refresh = "true"
data - show - fullscreen = "true"
data - show -
    export = "true"
data - height = "650" {
    # data - sticky - header = "true"
    #
} {
    # data - sticky - header - offset - left = "7em"
    #
} {
    # data - sticky - header - offset - right = "7em"
    #
}
data - click - to - select = "true"
data - id - field = "id"
data - show - footer = "true"
data - url = "/api/materials/"
data - query - params = "queryParams"
data - remember - order = "true"
data - pagination = "true"
data - side - pagination = "server"
data - total - field = "count"
data - data - field = "results" >
    <
    thead class = "thead-dark" >
    <
    tr contenteditable = 'true' >
    <
    th data - field = "id"
data - sortable = "true" > ID < /th> <
    th data - field = "courseCode"
data - sortable = "true"
data - formatter = "renderCourse" > Course Code < /th> <
    th data - field = "book.title"
data - sortable = "true"
data - formatter = "renderTitle" > Course Material Title < /th> <
    th data - field = "book.isbn"
data - sortable = "true" > ISBN < /th> <
    th data - field = "book.publisher"
data - sortable = "true" > Publisher < /th> <
    th data - field = "retail_price_display"
data - sortable = "true" > Retail Price < /th> <
    th data - field = "semester_course.school"
data - sortable = "true" > School < /th> <
    th data - field = "year"
data - sortable = "true" > Year < /th> <
    th data - field = "month"
data - sortable = "true" > Semester < /th> <
    th data - field = "quota"
data - sortable = "true" > Course Quota < /th> <
    /tr> <
    /thead> <
    /table>`  .


    <
    script > {
        % block script %
    }
const Content_Checklist = ['Course Code', 'Course Material Title'];
const eText_iBookStore = ['Course Code', 'eISBN/VBID', 'iSBN'];
const eText_Cost = ['Course Code', 'Course Material Title', 'e-isBN/VBID'];
const School = ['Course Code', 'School', 'Discipline'];
const Course = ['Course Code', 'Course Name', 'Starting Semester'];
const Stock = ['Course Code', 'Course Material Title', ];
const Billing = ['Course Code', 'Course Material Title', 'iSBN', 'e-isbn/vbid'];
var $table = $('#bk-table');
var $ok = $('#ok');


function queryParams(params) {
    params['limit'] = localStorage['Format'];
    params['discipline'] = localStorage['discipline'];
    params['Add_Information'] = localStorage['Add_Information'];
    if (params['Add_Information'] == "eText_iBookStore") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(eText_iBookStore[index]);

            console.log(eText_iBookStore[index]);
            console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
        });
    } else if (params['Add_Information'] == "Content_Checklist") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(Content_Checklist[index]);
            //here should change table data
        });
    } else if (params['Add_Information'] == "eText_Cost") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(eText_Cost[index]);
            //here should change table data
        });
    } else if (params['Add_Information'] == "School") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(School[index]);
            //here should change table data
        });
    } else if (params['Add_Information'] == "Course") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(Course[index]);
            //here should change table data
        });
    } else if (params['Add_Information'] == "Stock") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(Stock[index]);
            //here should change table data
        });
    } else if (params['Add_Information'] == "Billing") {
        $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).text(Billing[index]);
            //here should change table data
        });
    }

    params['publisher'] = $("[name='publisher']").val();
    params['code'] = $("[name='code']").val();
    console.log(params);
    return params;
}
```

In the if condition, each condition should have different table header and table data.
I have done the table header changing part, but have problem in table data changing part, how could I change the data part of my table？

Comment: `$(this).text()` writes the text.. so you have to make your changes before.

Comment: $(this).text() only changed the header, I want to change the data of the table

Comment: Ah sure. Well you can just select the matching `td` below instead of the `th`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting td by index with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139407/getting-td-by-index-with-jquery)

Comment: I do not have any td in my table, this could not work

Comment: I have tried all answer in that question, none works for me as I do not have any td in my table, the table data is rendered by attribute in header@Peter Krebs

Comment: Okay but what is keeping you from inserting the td elements yourself?

Comment: The table is rendered by restful api in django

Comment: You cannot run your script after the api results are rendered? You should add `Django` as a tag to your question.